# How to add markers to Mapbox layer control?

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I am using a simple Mapbox layer control calling MB data layers (below). 
I need to add a few more marker layers to this, but not sure how to get a mapbox ID.  How can I accomplish this?

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwc3RlciIsImEiOiI3RmFfME5ZIn0.73sdzUFNqSsGQzjlsnimaA';
var map = L.map('map').setView([38.8922,-77.0348], 14);
var layers = document.getElementById('menu-ui');

addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('examples.map-i87786ca'), 'Base Map', 1);
addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('examples.bike-lanes'), 'Bike Lanes', 2);
addLayer(L.mapbox.tileLayer('examples.bike-locations'), 'Bike Stations', 3);

function addLayer(layer, name, zIndex) {
    layer
        .setZIndex(zIndex)
        .addTo(map);
```

[code is from Mapbox toggling layers template](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/layers/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you're using their example ID and maps. You're not supposed to do that. If you would have read at the bottom of the page you posted it says:

> Use this example by copying its source into your own HTML page and replacing the Map ID with one of your own from your projects.

Where "your projects" is linked to https://www.mapbox.com/projects/. When you're not logged in you get a nice dialog which asks you to login or register. Once you've done that you'll get your very own ID and you are able to create projects. When creating a project you'll get a Map ID per project. It's all pretty selfexplanatory.

EDIT: If you want to insert a separate layer with features, you've got to create a project with only a markerlayer. Save it and copy the id. You can include that in another map by using `L.mapbox.featureLayer`:

```
var mapId = 'examples.map-zr0njcqy'; // use your feature mapid
var features = L.mapbox.featureLayer(mapId); // declare featureLayer

features.on('ready', function () { // Wait untill features are loaded
    addLayer(features); // add it the same your tilelayers
}
```

You can also use this to load external geojson files by just using an URL instead of a mapid.

See the example: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/features-from-another-map/
And the reference: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.1.5/l-mapbox-featurelayer/

Comment: I am using my own map IDs.  That code is from the template. I am interested in options to add marker layer to this.

Comment: Ok. I've edited my answer. But in your question you're saying that you're not sure on how to get a mapbox id. You could have been more clear. The question lacks a lot of things for instance: What did you research turn up? What did you try? What went wrong? What errors are you getting? See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask